# Google Cloud: Trying to automate https glb with Google-managed cert

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to automate glb configuration with DM scripts. I have been able to accomplish glb configurations with self provided certificate. However, I am now trying to use a Google-managed certificate. It's possible but I'm not able to automate it with a DM script because there are two gcloud commands:

```
gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates create [SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME] \
    --domains [DOMAIN]

gcloud beta compute [target-https-proxies | target-ssl-proxies] update [NAME] \
    --ssl-certificates [SSL-CERTIFICATE-NAME]
```

from https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates --> Creating a Google-managed SSL certificate resource

Is it possible to have some equivalent DM scripts so that I don't need to execute them from command-line or resort to using GCP console?